# fields_for not rendering - rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

Finally moved to Rails 3 for a new project and already running into a rookie problem.

Trying to do a simple nested form.

2 models: list and tasks

**List model**

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, :dependent=>:destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }
end
```

**Task Model**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list

end
```

**List Controller**

```
def new
   @list = List.new
   3.times{ @list.tasks.build }
end
```

**lists/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for :list, :url=>{:action=>"create"} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class=>'big' %>
    <%= f.label :name, "ex: Today's Todos, Christmas List" %>

    <% f.fields_for :tasks do |builder| %>
        <p>
            <%= builder.label :name, "Task" %>
            <%= builder.text_field :name %>
            <%= builder.check_box :_destroy %>
        </p>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= submit_tag "Create List", :id => "submit", :name => "submit", :class => "form_submit", :disabled => false, :disable_with => "Please wait..." %></p>

<% end -%>
```

Using **debug @list** I can see the 3 tasks I created in my controller, but it fields_for won't render.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

In rails 3, you should use `<%=` instead of `<%` for `form_for` and `fields_for` . See if that helps.

Comment: That fixed that problem ... now only 1 of 3 task text_fields are showing up ... any ideas?

Comment: nm ... got it.  I wasn't using the instance variable I created in the form_for

Comment: Cool, glad you got the problems solved. You may want to have a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form or https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic in the future to make rails forms easier to deal with.

Comment: OK, try this on rails 2.3.5: `return content_tag('li', render_single_menu_node(node, content_tag(:span, caption), url, selected), {}, false)`

Comment: I love you! Three days of research, and no solutions found. Except this!

Comment: Why do you need to use <%= instead of <%?

Comment: @Huey the helpers output viewable content, so it makes sense that your use `<%=` but in Rails 2 you had to use `<%` .

Comment: Ugh, so much of the Internet still has out of date information on fields_for, and it's such an easy one to miss reading the API docs. Horrible little issue! Thanks for the answer so much.

Comment: That saved me from pulling a few hairs out of my already bald head!

Answer (score 0):

In your list controller in action new you have to add

```
 def new
   @list = List.new
   3.times{ 
   @tasks = @list.tasks.build
   }
end
```