# Mongoid embeds_many with Rails fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, form-for, fields-for

I have a model like this:

```
class Search
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :terms

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :terms
end

class Terms
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :search, inverse_of: :terms

  field :some,    type: String
  field :search,  type: String
  field :terms,   type: String
end
```

and I have some haml that looks like:

```
= form_for @search do |f|
  - f.fields_for(:terms) do |term_form|
    = term_form.label :some
    = term_form.text_field :some
    = term_form.label :search
    = term_form.text_field :search
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

my Search#new method looks like:

```
@search = Search.new
@search.terms.build
```

and I would love it if anything showed up on the page, but it doesn't.

How do I make a form using form_for and fields_for the a Mongoid embeds_many embedded document?

For the record, I have also tried haml that looks like:

```
= form_for @search do |f|
  - @search.terms.each do |term|
    - f.fields_for(term) do |term_form|
....
```

and a few other variations, all to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414934/fields-for-not-rendering-rails-3) question had my answer.

rails 3 wants

`- f.fields_for(:terms) do |term_form|` to be:

`= f.fields_for(:terms) do |term_form|`

so it turns out it has absolutely nothing to do with mongoid relations at all. Stupid me for assuming.

Answer (score 2):

Your form seems fine - but i noticed there's a typo in your controller's action. Not sure if it's just a typo in your question, or in your actual app, but

```
@search.parties.build
```

should be

```
@search.terms.build
```

Comment: typo in question, I fixed it for clarity. Thanks.